# In R, generating every possible solution to a model, based on constraints

Tags: r, permutation

In R, I’m trying to generate a matrix that shows results from a model and the values used to solve them- all of which are constrained. Every possible solution. An example model:

> Model= a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2
>
> Where:
>
> 20≤Model≤30
>
> a=1
>
> 2 ≤b ≤3
>
> 2 ≤c ≤3
>
> 3 ≤d ≤4

I’d like the output to look like this:

```
    [a] [b] [c] [d] [Model]
[1]  1   3   2   3    23
[2]  1   2   2   4    25
[3]  1   3   3   3    28
[4]  1   2   3   3    23
```

Order doesn't matter. I just want the full permutation of feasible [integer] values. Any packages or help you could point my way?

In my example case, I want to generate all possible inputs(a,b,c,d) that hold valid, based on the parameters I set. I only want values from my output equation (Model) between 20 and 30. In this case, only 4 solutions are possible based on the criteria I'm setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're only looking for integer solutions, you can use `expand.grid()`

```
dd <- expand.grid(a=1, b=2:3, c=2:3, d=3:4)
m <- with(dd, a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)
inside <- function(x, a,b) a<=x & x<=b
cbind(dd, m)[inside(m, 20, 30),]

#   a b c d  m
# 2 1 3 2 3 23
# 3 1 2 3 3 23
# 4 1 3 3 3 28
# 5 1 2 2 4 25
# 6 1 3 2 4 30
# 7 1 2 3 4 30
```

(you said you want values <=30 but you seem to have left out the 30's in your example, you can change the `inside()` function of you want an open interval)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much. As a side note, I'm  incredibly disappointed in my inability to solve [by hand] the full number of possible solutions.

Comment: The `inside` function is a bit much? `cbind(dd,m)[m>=20 & m<=30,]` works as well.

Comment: @Spacedman Sure :) At fist i was avoiding the `m` variable with a `transform()` and I dislike typing a variable twice that I really only want to test once.

Comment: Urgh.. `colsums` and `rowsums` aren't available on 3.1.2. Is there any way create a column of the sum each row without the use of these commands?

Comment: @Andrew you mean colSums and rowSums? Function names are case sensitive.

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks for all of the help. :)